# Trigger to create parent and child records from set of one object records - update is not working

Tags: apex, triggercontext, trigger

I have one object named "Order_batch__c" .In that i have records in such a way

[image]

I want to separate the data into two records one is parent object "order" and child object  "order item"

1. order consists of fields : customer po,account name, customer id
2. order item consists of fields : nicomatic pin,quantity ordered

Trigger:

```
    trigger orderitem on order_batch__c (after insert , after update) {
    order__c[] orders = new order__c[] {};
    order__c[] uporders=new order__c[]{};
    set<string> ids=new set<string>();
    set<string> ids1=new set<string>();
    for (order_batch__c ob : Trigger.new){
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
   orders.add(new order__c(Customer_Po__c = ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c));
   ids.add(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c);
    }
     if(Trigger.isupdate)
        {
     ids.add(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c);
     }
    }
    insert orders;

list<order__c> ord= new list<order__c>([select id,Customer_Po__c from order__c where Customer_Po__c in:ids ]);
for (order__c ob : ord){
   uporders.add(new order__c(id=ob.id,Customer_Po__c = ob.Customer_Po__c));     
          }
    update uporders;

    Order_Item__c[] upitems = new Order_Item__c[] {};
    Order_Item__c[] items = new Order_Item__c[] {};   
    Integer index = 0;
    for (order_batch__c ob : Trigger.new)
    {
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
        {
 items.add(new Order_Item__c(
                Name = ob.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,
                Client_PN__c = ob.Or_clientpn__c,
                Quantity__c = ob.Quantity_Ordered__c,
                Request_Date__c = ob.Requested_Date__c,
                Discount__c = ob.Discount__c,
                Price__c = ob.Unit_price__c,
                Order__c = orders[index].Id
                ));
        index++;
    }
 if(Trigger.isupdate)
 {
  ids1.add(ob.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c);
 }
 }
    insert items;

List<Order_Item__c> orderlineitem=new list<order_item__c>([select id ,name,Order_customer_po_number__c from order_item__c where Order_customer_po_number__c In:ids and name in:ids1]);
for (order_item__c ob : orderlineitem){
   upitems.add(new order_item__c(id=ob.id,name = ob.name));     
          }
    update upitems;

}
```

My requirement is to  separate records in parent and child records .when ever there is an update in order batch records it has to update accordingly parent or child.

I am getting error in the above trigger .can any body help me regarding this

Comment: Hi, what error are you getting, do you mean as update trigger fires or insert trigger fires, you want to create Parent/Child records?

Comment: @AmitBangad Error Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to SOBJECT:order__c at line 12 column 26

Comment: Both update and insert i want to fire triger .currently i am trying for insertion after i will update code for updation

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: order__c.temp at line 12 column 28

Comment: @Keith C .my records updated functionality not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do want to create an ID-based relationship between Order_Item__c and Order__c, you will first have to insert the Order__c objects so their IDs are allocated. Bulkifying too, you end up with (may contain typos):

```
trigger orderitem on order_batch__c (after insert , after update) {

    order__c[] orders = new order__c[] {};
    for (order_batch__c ob : Trigger.new)
    {
        orders.add(new order__c(
                Customer_Po__c = ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c
                ));
    }
    insert orders;

    Order_Item__c[] items = new Order_Item__c[] {};
    Integer index = 0;
    for (order_batch__c ob : Trigger.new)
    {
        items.add(new Order_Item__c(
                Name = ob.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,
                Client_PN__c = ob.Or_clientpn__c,
                Quantity__c = ob.Quantity_Ordered__c,
                Request_Date__c = ob.Requested_Date__c,
                Discount__c = ob.Discount__c,
                Price__c = ob.Unit_price__c,
                Order__c = orders[index].Id
                ));
        index++;
    }
    insert items;
}
```

But by including "after update" you run the danger of many objects being created; perhaps for the update case the trigger should search for and update the Order__c and Order_Item__c records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but update will be done from main order_batch__c

Comment: @Teja This trigger will fire and do more inserts as written at the moment.

Comment: k fine .thankyou

Comment: @Teja Your current edits won't compile; I suggest if you choose to edit a answer you add to the answer not replace it.

Comment: .i am sorry .I thought i am editing question .

Comment: .I had worked on update to this answer .but value is not getting updated .can you find out what the issue is .I had updated question regarding this

Comment: @Teja I've put by original answer back.

Comment: .I dont see any option to revert back .otherwise i would have done the same

Comment: @Teja Yeah the editing history on answers appears to not be as good as on questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can replace line 12 by :

```
o.Customer_Po__c= temp.Or_customer_PO_Number__c;
```

your primary error will be removed!

Cheers,